# install opencv in visual studion 2017

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I would like to install *OpenCV* in *Visual Studio* and I have tried several ways and I still have the same problems..

[image: Error message]

The code doesn't have any errors.
The code says that `LNK2019` unresolved external symbol.

1. Install through the Package Manager Console: PM> Install-Package opencvdefault (c++)
2. Install through Manage Nuget Package for Solution: opencv.win.native (c++)
3. Install the file from in internet: opencv_python-3.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32 (python)

What am I doing wrong? I want to use it in `VS 2017` with C++ or Python.

Comment: OpenCV is a bit of a pain to install. What is "opencv.exe"? If it's your own exe that you tried to build, it does have *linking* errors - an unresolved external symbol. What is your unresolved external symbol? You normally compile your own exe (or an opencv example) and *link* to the opencv library.

Comment: OpenCV is a library I never seen OpenCV.exe...

Comment: @Pam Considering that [OpenCV ships prebuilt binaries](https://opencv.org/releases.html) for this compiler, it's a matter of download, unpack, set up include/link paths and you're set to go. Even without any fancy package managers it seems rather trivial.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" IMHO the main problem is that you're jumping ahead of yourself. You clearly don't understand what a linker is or does, and are baffled by it to the point that you disregard the contents of the error message it produced. That tells me you're not ready to develop a computer vision system, working with complex third party libraries. Grab a C++ book, and master the basics of your language of choice (including topics like writing and using simple libraries) first. In other words, learn to walk, before you try to run a Marathon.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, I think I found those Android ones previously but forgot about them. The whole CMAKE process would have put any beginner right off!

Comment: @Pam Yeah, building your own is definitely a different story...

Comment: @DanMašek  thx for comment. I'm new in computer vision therefore I know I have a lot of think need to study more. Back to my problems, I had link the with the OpenCV 3.4.1 download from https://opencv.org/releases.html, the library is link at 1) C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\opencv\opencv\build\include
2) Linker-> General ->Additional Library Directories->C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin 3) Linker-> Input ->Additional Dependencies -> opencv_world341d.lib 4) environment variable -> Path -> C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin.

Comment: Those steps is the way I link with opencv and the problem still can't solve

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to download OpenCV sources from opencv.org and latest version of CMake installation kit from cmake.org.
You will be able to built OpenCV on your own PC. My own experience indicated that it's quite easy and Open CV works without any problems.
CMAke has a support for MS Visual Studio 15 (also called MS Visual Studio 2017)

[image]

Comment: have you try with vs 2017...CMake don't have the features for VS 2017

Comment: I added a picture to my answer. The latest version of CMake has a support for VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

So you have created a project called 'opencv', only slightly confusing the question.

First thing to decide is if you want to use Visual Studio (C++) or Python?

If Visual Studio, I suggest downloading the latest library from the OpenCV website (select 'Win pack') https://opencv.org/releases.html

In your project you will then need to include the OpenCV header folder, and link to the (lib) libraries, then make sure your executable is able to find the main opencv dll library.

I do not recommend compiling the OpenCV library with Cmake - this is not trivial (I've spent half a day on it and failed) - moreover it's not necessary as OpenCV can be used as is.

Comment: yeah the project is called 'opencv'. The library is link at 1) C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\opencv\opencv\build\include 2) Linker-> General ->Additional Library Directories->C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin 3) Linker-> Input ->Additional Dependencies -> opencv_world341d.lib 4) environment variable -> Path -> C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin. Those steps is the way I link with opencv and the problem still can't solve

Comment: I assume your project type is x64, debug. The first setting is in the Project properties, in 'VC++ Directories': Add the include folder to 'Include Directories' (no need to set additional one elsewhere), and in 'Library Directories': 'C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib'. Notice 'lib' at the end.